# Characterise, via Naimark's theorem, the POVM corresponding to a PVM in a dilated space

Tags: measurement, quantum-operation, povm

Let $F\equiv\{F^a\}_a$ be a POVM in some finite-dimensional Hilbert space $\mathcal X$. It is [well-known](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naimark%27s_dilation_theorem) that one can always understand $F$ as a projective measurement (PVM) in an isometrically enlarged space. More precisely, defining $V_F:\mathcal X\to\mathcal Y\otimes \mathcal X$ as
$$V_F u \equiv \sum_a |a\rangle\otimes (\sqrt{F^a}\,u), \qquad u \in\mathcal X$$
one verifies that $V_F$ is an isometry and $F^a=V_F^\dagger (\mathbb{P}_a\otimes I)V_F$ with $\mathbb{P}_a\equiv|a\rangle\!\langle a|$.

Let me now consider a slightly different scenario: let $W:\mathcal X\to\mathcal Y\otimes\mathcal X$ be *some* isometry (not necessarily tied to any specific POVM). We can now build a corresponding POVM describing evolution through this isometry followed by a PVM on the ancillary space. This reads
$$(F_W)^a \equiv W^\dagger (\mathbb{P}_a\otimes I)W.$$
Any isometry can be decomposed wrt a basis for $\mathcal Y$ as
$$W u= \sum_a |a\rangle\otimes (W_a u), \qquad u\in\mathcal X,$$
but in general, the operators $W_a\equiv (\langle a|\otimes I)W:\mathcal X\to\mathcal X$ are *not* positive semidefinite operators. The only thing we can say about them is that, due to the isometric constraint $W^\dagger W=I$, they must satisfy $\sum_a W_a^\dagger W_a=I$ (*i.e.* they can always be understood as the Kraus operators for some channel).

But then again, given $F_W$, I could follow the construction in Naimark's theorem to obtain another isometry, call it $V_{F_W}$, whish has the form
$$V_{F_W} = \sum_a |a\rangle\otimes \sqrt{(F_W)^a}.$$

I'm not entirely sure what to make of this: $F_W$ is clearly a POVM for any isometry $W$, but then it doesn't seem like $V_{F_W}$ equals $W$ in general (as $W_a$ won't necessarily be positive semidefinite, while the corresponding blocks of $V_{F_W}$ are). But still, both isometries feel like they are performing a similar kind of operation. Is there a way to see whether they are indeed "equivalent", at least as far as the measurement at hand is concerned?

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/226477/deriving-a-povm-from-a-projective-measurement?rq=1

I think this might be relevant, although the answer is not fully clear to me. If you get it could you please help me with it?

Comment: Please don't use Watrous notation, reading this is torture.

Comment: @MateusAraújo I mean, that's pretty subjective, but which part are you referring to exactly? Using $\mathcal X$ rather than $\mathcal H$ for spaces? Or $\mu(a)$ instead of $\mu_a$? The latter I use mostly because $\sqrt{\mu_a}$ doesn't render very nicely in latex imo, and it's easier to adapt when I have to use an index to denote POVMs as in here

Comment: In general that this notation gratuitously breaks the conventions used in hundreds of papers, so we have to look at the definition of each symbol to know what it means, instead of just knowing. Using lowercase Latin letters for operators, for example. These are vectors in pretty much any paper you'll find on the arXiv. Also, POVM elements are $E^a$ or $F^a$, projectors are $P^a$ or $\Pi^a$. Now a *real-valued* measured is written as $\mu(a)$. Using this notation for operator-valued measures is just evil.

Comment: @MateusAraújo eh. Fwiw, I don't use lowercase latin letters for operators. Here $u$ is a vector, if that's what you're referring to. I probably should have used $|u\rangle$ rather $u$ to make it more obvious. I admit I didn't b/c I found the resulting equation not that nice to look at, which I know it's a weak justification. I could use $F^a$ for POVM elements, but at the end of the day, I feel like either what the symbol means is obvious from the structure of the equation and the context, or one has to look up what it's used to represent anyway, so I didn't think too much of it.

Comment: also, I admit I'm not *that* familiar with the topical literature, so I don't really know which notation is more standard or not. Watrous' book is the first place where I found these topics written down in a way that I found sufficiently rigorous and "neat", and that's probably why I tend to find that style of notation more aesthetically appealing now.

Comment: Ah. I was sure it must be an operator acting on $\mathcal X$ because you used $|a\rangle$ for vectors in $\mathcal Y$.

Comment: @MateusAraújo the reason I used $u$ rather than $|u\rangle$ was partly esthetic, and partly b/c I prefer to reserve kets for normalised vectors, whereas here I'm technically specifying the action of the operator on a generic vector.

Comment: A ket is just a vector, it doesn't need to be normalised. You're just making sure nobody can understand what you write.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define
$$
V_F^S u \equiv \sum_a |a\rangle\otimes (S^a\sqrt{F^a}\,u), \qquad u \in\mathcal X,
$$
where $S^a$ is any unitary. Then $V_F^S$ is also an isometry and
$$
F^a=(V_F^S)^\dagger (\mathbb{P}_a\otimes I)V_F^S.
$$

In fact, for any $W$ with the property $F^a=W^\dagger (\mathbb{P}_a\otimes I)W$ there exists a set of $S^a$  such that $W = V_F^S$. It follows from the polar decomposition of $W_a$.

Comment: ah, brilliant, makes perfect sense. Given any POVM $F_W$ corresponding to measurement through a given isometry $W$, we can find some set of unitaries $S$ such that the associated "Naimark's dilation isometry" $V_F^S$ satisfies $W=V_F^S$.